# Unable to save version on Magento Connect extension upload

Tags: extensions, magento-connect, version

I used to upload new version for my extension with no issue, but this time i am getting this error "Unable to save version".

[image]

Comment: You may get the answer here but you will prob have better luck asking on the official Magento forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had similar problem. Actually I found an answer in [docs](http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf)

> 1. Remember that the name is case sensitive. Your package must be identical to the name listed on the extension profile page.
> 2. Channel is case sensitive. Always use lower case community
> 3. The lead author listed when packaging the extension must be the user who is uploading the extension or the upload will result in an
>      error.
> 4. Package using “User Name” not “Screen Name” or the upload will result in an error.

I suggest to check point **2**, as it's a most common problem. What does it mean? When you create a package, check if "community" is written using *lower letters* only.

Comment: Check same version stability like stable development etc in packing & extension profile page